# Add or Subtracting into $(window).scrollTop + $(window).height == $(document).height() - Scrolled to bottom of page equation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm running an if function when the user gets to the bottom of the page which works great as is like this

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {}
```

However I want it to run slightly before the bottom - about 300px before.

I've tried

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + 300 == $(document).height()) {}
```

AND

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height() -300) {}
```

and all other variations to no avail.

I've also tried putting variables in.

```
var plusheight = 300;

if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + plusheight == $(document).height()) {}
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + $plusheight == $(document).height()) {}
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() + "plusheight" == $(document).height()) {}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's hard to get exactly 300px above the bottom...

Comment: It's hard to a user scrolls exactly to -300px from bottom. You should use greater then `>` or less then `<`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an inequality.  It's quite possible the user's scrolltop is jumping right past the exact value you're comparing with.

```
if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() -300) {}
```

Comment: Of course, so simple. After looking at it for so long logic was starting to fly out the window. Thanks.